# value from unique elements

Tags: r, binary, uniqueidentifier

I'm writing a QC program in R to handle data from an instrument that reports its own error codes. The codes are reported as bit values, so

```
0
```

means "all OK", while:-

```
1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128
```

Each represent a unique error. Multiple errors can occur simultaneously, in which case the codes are summed to give a new number, e.g:-

```
error "2" + error "32" = code "34"
```

And because these sums are each unique, any given code value can be broken down into its constituent errors. I'm looking for a way to program the identification of errors from these codes. I'm struggling with an approach, but everything I can think of involves either look-up-tables or a big stack of loops... neither of which seems very elegant.

Rather than re-invent the wheel, I'm wondering if there's an `R` function that already exists to do this.

Has anyone come across this sort of problem before?

Comment: if you have all powers of 2, you can use a bitwise OR, eg. `bitwOr(1,2)`.  Then, disambigulation of the error is just if a 1 occurs at that position, eg. `bitwAnd(bitwOr(1,2),2)`

Comment: Nice solution @jenesaisquoi! Florian's answer suits this case very well, but I was unaware of the bitwise operators in R, so this is really helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could convert the number to bits, and use that representation to find the errors.

```
2^(which(intToBits(34)==1)-1)
```

returns

```
2 32
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice solution +1~

Comment: I just finished coding a for-loop method, but this is vastly superior (1 line instead of 20+) - thanks Florian!

Comment: Glad I could help!